# How to effectively manage multiple URL responses in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

**Background**:

I have a script that runs analytics against a series of URL response objects (json).  I do this by iterating over a dictionary containing the URLs, and then dynamically creating filenames and writing those files to disk, performing the analytics upon opening the files into memory.

**I would like to eliminate the IO in the script and push this downstream to my users who could run it themselves in a Jupyter notebook using pandas dataframes to do the table presentation/logic**.

This is the code snippet that I am unsure how to modify:

```
for key, value in url_dict.items():
    print("Issuing query for {}".format(key))
    json_response = s.get(value, verify=cert_authority)
    data = json_response.json()
    jsonfilename = 'query_' + key + '.json'
    jsonfile = os.path.join(query_output_directory, jsonfilename)
    with open(jsonfile, 'wb') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to pipe the various json response objects into their own variables; e.g., instead of just `data` I need `data1`, `data2`, etc.  It feels like I need dynamic variables but I am sure there must be a far less janky solution.

Comment: Why not a append to a list of json responses?

Comment: Oh boy that recommendation is so simple that I missed it entirely.  If you want to toss together an example and submit it as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Haha, no problem! It happens all the time, usually before that first cup of coffee in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append the responses to a list as you loop through.

```
alljsonvariables=[]
for key, value in url_dict.items():
    print("Issuing query for {}".format(key))
    json_response = s.get(value, verify=cert_authority)
    alljsonvariables.append(json_response.json())
#the rest of your code goes here
```